# Find out which filters were applied to an email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I've got about 20-30 filters set up in my work Gmail account doing a range of things, from filtering newsletters that won’t let me unsubscribe into the bin, to marking messages that come through a web form and putting them in a separate folder etc.

One of the filters is acting odd because when I reply to some emails, instead of the response ending up in the sent for some reason it’s getting moved into my inbox—so that my sent message now sits in my inbox.

Because I’ve got quite a few filters, I’m not sure which one is doing this—is there a way to see which filters have been applied to an email in Gmail?

Comment: Don't know if you can do it now, but for the future, maybe add a label with a name to all filters, and you'll see the label on the email so you'll know from which filter the problem comes...

Comment: Strongly related to: [View filter(s) that are currently being applied to an email message](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92723/354)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your filters are doing this? I've never heard of a filter that acts on outgoing messages.

Are you replying to an email list, and since you are subscribed to the list, the message is also delivered to you (in your inbox)?

Answer (score -1):

As @Vidar already stated in his answer, filter usually work for incoming messages.

The only other reason I can think of is `conversation view`.

To change this:

1. click settings (the wrench on the right)
2. turn off conversation view (7th item in the list of settings)
   [image]

When it's turned of check to see if you have the desired result.

---

Edit:

To see which filters are applied to a certain message, just open the message and see all filters applied after the title.

[image]

In the image the title of the mail message is "Email in Spam" and the filters applied are `inbox` and `corestats`

### List of filters and what they do

To see a list of all the filters, what they do and an option to delete;

1. Go to settings
2. Click on filters and blocked addresses
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not answer the question: 
which filters were applied to an email?

Comment: OP is referring to mails being in his inbox, if you just need to know which filter is applied to a certain message, all filters applied to a message are right after the title if you open the message (in grey). Updated my answer.

Comment: these are not the filters... these are the labels. A filter may add a label, but it may do a lot of other things that are not related to labels.

Comment: the last addition to your post shows the list of filters in general, but not the list of filters applied to a specific email message.