# View filter(s) that are currently being applied to an email message

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I created a bunch of filters in Gmail for a "master account" that receives forwarded mail from all of my accounts.  The filter list and web of labels/folders has grown to be rather long, and therefore a bit burdensome to manage. I would like to edit / delete / consolidate a lot of these filter rules (and folders) but it seems the only way I can interface with them is through the laundry list at Setting/Filters. It'd be cool there was an option to "View/Edit Filter" on an individual email's page, but I'm not sure if something like that currently exists.

What's the best way to view a filter rule currently being applied to an email (in Gmail)?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately neither the GmailApp API nor the advanced Gmail API have any way to read your filters let alone what filters were applied to an email.

Assigning each filter a unique label to assign will let you see their effects going forward.

However there is one more way to look at your list of filters aside from the Gmail settings. You can export the filters to an XML file. This file has the advantage of being searchable with in a simple text editor. More advance editors like Notepad++ have additional features for manipulating XML files.

I did find a wiki post with [shell script](http://wiki.tcl.tk/39733) to turn the XML file into a CSV for even simpler reading. That post has links to other implementations of the same idea.